# node-sass command not found when compiling

Tags: node.js, macos, sass

I have a problem with SASS for node.js on Mac (OS X El Capitan)

When i trying compile a scss file to css using command 'node-sass -o css sass/style.scss' I get the following error:

> node-sass: command not found

What's the problem and how i can solve it?

Comment: Did you install the package globally (`npm install -g node-sass`) or locally? If locally, the CLI tool can be called as `./node_modules/.bin/node-sass`.

Comment: I tried both ways. Nothing works...

Comment: When it's installed globally, you need to have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH` environment variable. Or call it with a full path: `/usr/local/bin/node-sass -o ...`

Comment: Strange, but it didn't working. Maybe i doing something wrong. On Windows in's working good

Comment: What does this return: `ls -al /usr/local/bin/node-sass`? It's working fine on my Mac so it's not OS-related. Are you using `nvm` or another Node version manager?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/node-sass: No such file or directory - I get this error

Comment: That means it isn't installed globally. Are you using a Node version manager like `nvm` or something?

Answer (score 15):

It means command `node-sass` is missing in your system.
`node-sass` is a node.js command which can be installed with

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

The `-g` switch means a node.js command which can run globally is being installed. Without `-g` means a node.js library is being installed at current directory.

Answer (score 12):

try this: 
`npx node-sass -o css sass/style.scss`

`npx` will check whether `<command>` exists in `$PATH`, or in the local project binaries, and execute it. The more detail explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm)

Comment: could you add a description as to what does this statement do?

Answer (score 6):

This helped me:

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g node-sass
```

Comment: Worked! I missed `--unsafe-perm` and it caused issues in linux for `node-sass` module

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was getting errors like this because `npm install` didn't run correctly. removing my node_modules and then rerunning that command removed my build errors.

Answer (score 0):

go to https://github.com/sass/node-sass
download .zip or clone repo add el folder node-sass in node-modules and en file package-lock.json add this.

```
"node-sass": {
  "version": "4.7.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass/-/node-sass-4.7.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-CaV+wLqZ7//Jdom5aUFCpGNoECd7BbNhjuwdsX/LkXBrHl8eb1Wjw4HvWqcFvhr5KuNgAk8i/myf/MQ1YYeroA==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "async-foreach": "0.1.3",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "cross-spawn": "3.0.1",
    "gaze": "1.1.2",
    "get-stdin": "4.0.1",
    "glob": "7.1.2",
    "in-publish": "2.0.0",
    "lodash.assign": "4.2.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "4.5.0",
    "lodash.mergewith": "4.6.1",
    "meow": "3.7.0",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "nan": "2.8.0",
    "node-gyp": "3.6.2",
    "npmlog": "4.1.2",
    "request": "2.79.0",
    "sass-graph": "2.2.4",
    "stdout-stream": "1.4.0",
    "true-case-path": "1.0.2"
  },
```

ok now

```
~$ npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
pwd
```

Checkout to your project directory,  for `eg:desktop`

```
ls -la
```

Then see your project name and its position. Whether it’s in root.
If its in root,

```
sudo chown -R <change to your position from root><projectname>/
cd <projectname>
cd ../
rm -rf node_modules/
ls
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

to use sass you must have node installed and than use the following command

```
sudo npm install -g node-sass
```

this is for linux users only, if you have not used "sudo" you will get the following error

```
node-sass not found
```

Answer (score 0):

At the same folder where you have the package.json file, open terminal and type this:

```
npm install node-sass
```

If after install this dependency still failling, remove node_modules and type:

```
npm install
```

npm install will rebuild your node_modules folder with package.json dependencies updated (Previously, you install node-sass in package.json with 'npm install node-sass' command).

Answer (score 0):

I tried an npm install but that didn't install the node-sass binary. I ended up having to run

`yarn --cwd assets`