# Testcafe command not found when installed through "npm install"

Tags: testing, automated-tests, npm-install, e2e-testing, testcafe

When I installed testcafe with command `sudo npm install -g testcafe` I was able to use the command "testcafe" in the terminal, running tests like `testcafe browser test`, but now I formatted my OS and installed it with just `npm install` with the packege.json of my project and when I try to use "testcafe" command to run tests I get the message `testcafe: command not found`.

Now I'm able to run tests just if I call the node module, like `/usr/bin/node node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe.js browser test`

It seems that the "testcafe" command alias to call the node module was not created when I installed it with just `npm install`.

Any thoughts on how can I fix it or why this happened?

Comment: Can you show us your packege.json?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is expected behavior. If you want to use the `testcafe` command from the command line, you need to install the testcafe package globally using the `-g` argument.
Please refer to the following article to get more details:
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/installing-testcafe.html

Answer (score 6):

As a feedback on how to install TestCafe, I recommend to install it locally instead of globally, especially if your tests are executed in a CI environment, because a CI environment may be reformatted at any time (like your dev machine) or may be used by different tenants that might each needs a special version of TestCafe.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [npx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm) to run any local binary without installing it globally.