# json-server is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, npm, json-server

I am setting up a json-server and I install it and assign it to be my npm start command like so

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "json-server -p 3001 -w db.json"
```

but every time I type npm start on the terminal I got this error

```
> api-server@1.0.0 start C:\Work\React-projects\streams\api-server
> json-server -p 3001 -w db.json

'json-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! api-server@1.0.0 start: `json-server -p 3001 -w db.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the api-server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abdelaziz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-06T09_07_30_796Z-debug.log
```

Comment: How did you install json-server ?

Comment: @ArnaudChrist
I tried everything 
``` npm install -g json-server --save ```

Comment: For people visiting.. you can directly use NPX to watch a json file without even installing json-server like so "npx json-server --watch ./data/filename.json"

Answer (score 136):

First, you need to check `json-server` installed globally or not. or you can install it globally by

```
npm install -g json-server
```

If you install it locally in your project, use `npx` to run it

```
npx json-server --watch db.json
```

Checkout difference between npx and npm here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018825/11285186

Comment: I installed it globally still not working, I tried npx it show this 
(
npx: installed 236 in 8.971s
command not found: json-server
)

Comment: Hi, you can run `npm list -g --depth 0` and check `json-server` in the list or not?

Comment: I got this : C:\Users\Abdelaziz\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- create-react-app@2.1.8
+-- gulp-cli@2.1.0
+-- http-server@0.11.1
+-- json-server@0.14.2
+-- npm@6.9.0
`-- sudo@1.0.3

Comment: So, next step is check your PATH environment, make sure it has `C:\Users\Abdelaziz\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: did that several times and still have the same error

Comment: try following `node "C:\Users\Abdelaziz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\bin\index.js" -p 3001 -w db.json`

Comment: nothing I can't even find bin directory in my json-server folders just lib,dist and nodes_modules

Comment: i'm having the exact same problem. it worked for about a year now. all of a sudden, whatever i do: json-server command unknown

Comment: Adding PATH environment fixed it for me

Answer (score 14):

First step you install the json server using the following command: 
**npm install -g json-server**
Then, you can run the command and select the port using the following command:
**npx json-server --watch -p 3333 server.json**
*Change **3333** to the port number you want and replace **server.json** with the name of your fake api.*

In my case, I'm using React js and my server.json is at the root of my application.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
npm i -g json-server 

json-server --watch db.json
```

if this don't work

```
npm i -g json-server 

npx json-server --watch db.json
```

and this way works for mac

Answer (score 3):

Update the node.js version, Works on versions above node.js 10 versions.

Answer (score 3):

I got into the Same Problem When I tried to add the json-server as a script in the package.json file so as to run it using

`npm run start`

got the error **"json-server is not recognized as an internal or external command"**

a quick solution is to Modify the scripts as

`"scripts": {  "start": "npx json-server -p 3001 -w db.json" }`

another way is

`"scripts": {  "server" : "npx json-server --watch db.json --port 3001" }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

1. npm i -g json-server
2. go to your application path example:\angular\TestApps\src\assets\mockdata>
3. run npx json-server --watch .\db.json   Ex: here db.josn is my fake web api
4. this will run json server on http://localhost:3000/ without any issue

Answer (score 0):

The common mistake is not installing the **json-sever package Globally** !

What worked for me : I used the command :

> npm install -g json-server

(-g is for globally installing a package)

For testing :

> json-server --watch data/db.json --port 8000
> (--watch is use to check for database file [here path - data data/db.json] and --port is used to set port manually [here 8000])

You can check data on port 8000 now,

> http://localhost:8000/anything

(You can use npx also)