# Why do I get a Can not find module error when I run npx run dev?

Tags: node.js

Why do I get a Can not find module error when I run npx run dev?

before run 'npx run dev'

I processed this

Run the npm init command
Webpack webpack-cli installation
Configuring webpack.conifig.js
Setting package.json
node upgrade
Creating client.jsx
WordRelay.jsx component file creation etc.

webpack.conifig.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    name:'wordrelay-setting',
    mode:'development',
    devtool:'eval',
    resolve:{
        extensions:['.js','.jsx']
    },

    entry:{
        app:['./client']
    }, // 입력

    output: {
        path:path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename:'app.js'
    },  // 출력

};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "lecture",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "hyun",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.37.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

and github: 
https://github.com/hyunsokstar/react_game_prac2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run webpack but you not let webpack know what config it should take. So it will run with default config. Which have `entry` set to `src/index.js`. You need to run webpack and point it to your config file (The file name is incorrect so please fix it).

Another problem is that you use `jsx` in your code but you don't use `babel` to compile `jsx` to `js`. So you need to add `babel` to your project.

The last problem is you have some error syntax in `client.jsx` file.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "lecture",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "hyun",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.37.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
process.env.NODE_ENV='development';

module.exports = {
    name:'wordrelay-setting',
    mode:'development',
    devtool:'eval',
    resolve:{
        extensions:['.js','.jsx']
    },

    entry:{
        app:['./client']
    }, // 입력

    output: {
        path:path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename:'app.js'
    },  // 출력

    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader"
            }
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

client.jsx

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDom = require('react-dom');

const WordRelay = require('./WordRelay')
React.render(<WordRelay />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

> Original answer

When you use this command `npx run dev`. You are executing a `run` module. That is why you get the error. The correct command should be

```
npm run dev
```

[Difference between npx and npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm)

Comment: thank you and another error is occured 
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\react_game_prac2'
can you help me ?

Comment: Please share your project structure. I think the problem is you set your ```entry``` wrongly.

Comment: git hub is this : https://github.com/hyunsokstar/react_game_prac2

thanks

Comment: react_game_prac2 is root and everty thing is same with github thank you

Comment: I guess it was caused by the file name being conifig.js.

I also installed a barbell loader.

The problem has been solved.  very thank you.