# package.json: how to test if node_modules exists

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-run

Inside **package.json**, is it possible to test if `node_modules` directory exists?
My goal is to print a message if `node_module` does not exists, something like:

```
node_module not existent: use npm run dist
```

where `dist` is a script inside `scripts` of my package.json.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by B M in comments, I've created the following script named `checkForNodeModules.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
if (!fs.existsSync('./node_modules'))
  throw new Error(
    'Error: node_modules directory missing'
  );
```

And inside my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "node-modules-check": "checkForNodeModules.js",
  "start": "npm run node-modules-check && node start-app.js",
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I thought I would post what I've done for cross-platform one-liner conditional NPM scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "start":"(node -e \"if (! require('fs').existsSync('./node_modules'))
{process.exit(1)} \" || echo 
'node_module dir missing: use npm run dist') && node start-app.js",
}
```

Comment: Clever, not quite right for the OP, but up-voted irrespectively as it adds value.

Comment: That is, consider changing the hard-coded values `./bin/helpers` as well as `setup-helpers` and `npm run final-build-step` to match the original question at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, via npm `scripts`. Which [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to use is your choice. If your application starts via `npm start` (good practice) use the `start` script to add your check:

`"scripts": { "start" : "./test.sh" }`

The actual test for the directory can be implemented via a shell script or a NodeJs script, consider using `npx` as discussed in [Difference between npx and npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm).

Comment: I see two issues: on Unix like systems `test.sh` will run but on Windows systems will not; npx executes npm binaries, but at time 0, I have no node_modules directory, so what executable to run, a global one? What if a colleague with brand new node installation has no global executables?

Comment: If you need a platform independent solution `npx` will be the better choice. It will install packages guessing them by the name of the command to run.

Comment: Sorry but I need a snippet to better understand this. So what to write inside `"scripts"` section? Something like `"test": "npx what?`

Comment: The probably simplest solution, no `npx` needed: `"scripts": { "start" : "node test.js && node start-app.js" }` while in `test.js`: `if (! fs.existsSync('./node_modules')) throw new Error('node_modules not found...');`. Personally I think that running an `npm install` should be solved elsewhere, e. g. in a CI/CD pipeline, but technically this should work.

Comment: Thank you B M, that is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

With this script I have run `yarn install`  in subfolder `app` of my project dir (if node_modules not exist)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const spawn = require('cross-spawn');

if (!fs.existsSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/node_modules'))) {
  
  const result = spawn.sync(
    'yarn',
    ['--cwd', path.resolve(__dirname, '../app'), 'install'],
    {
      stdio: 'inherit'
    }
  );
  console.log(result);
}
```