# Having Trouble creating a React Application

Tags: reactjs

When I was trying to create a React application, the window was frozen at a point and there is nothing happening.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Sg4.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between npx and npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm)

Comment: When I get it frozen like that, it usually doesn't resume, and doing ctrl-c and restarting usually fixes the issue. This goes for all npm commands in general, when they freeze

Answer (score 0):

If you're using npm `create-react-app`, this might cause some unforeseen issues, as it is no longer support.
You should make sure you use `npx create-react-app`, or `npx create-react-app --template` if you want the boilerplate code, as they changed it to not include boilerplate code by default, leaving you with only `package.json`, `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`.

Alternatively you can use `yarn create react-app` and `yarn create react-app --template` respectively.