# using the npx command to run a react-native project

Tags: react-native, npx

Previously, when I had tried using react-native we were told to use `react-native run-ios` to run the project from the command line. Now, the instructions say to use `npx react-native run-ios` from the command line.

What in the benefit of using `npx`. Does using npx change how the project is compiled? If I sometimes use `npx` and sometimes neglect to use it will it mess anything up in my project?

Answer (score 1):

[Check this answer more about of `npx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018825/2955679)

---

**react-native supported and recommended to use `npx` start from `react-native@0.60.0`.**

The benefit of using `npx` is don't need to install react-native-cli tools globally. Check the below example of using `npx` and not for the react-native project.

```sh
### Using npx ###
﹩ npx react-native init <SimpleProjectName>
```

```sh
### Without using npx ###
﹩ npm i -g react-native-cli
﹩ react-native init <SimpleProjectName>
```

Both `react-native-cli` and `npx react-native` are should not use in one project. The official docs said before starting a new project:

> If you previously installed a global `react-native-cli` package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues.