# Command 'jest' not found, did you mean: command 'test' from deb coreutils Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

Tags: jestjs

Jest is installed but when I was trying to generate `jest.config.js` file with `./node_modules/.bin/jest --init`, I got this error:

```
Command 'jest' not found, did you mean:
command 'test' from deb coreutils
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `npx jest --init` which will run the local package from the project.

Answer (score 2):

The following is applicable for packages other than `jest` but I am using this one as an example. The processes are usually analogous for most other Node packages.

## Running locally

The issue is that `jest` is installed *locally* just for this project. There are few ways to do this:

### `npx` (recommended)

The easiest way to use it like this is to use `npx` (see: [difference with `npm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm)) which will execute a Node package.

```
npx jest --init
```

The `npx` tool will first try the locally installed packages and if not found, it will download and run the package as a one off, then remove it.

### Adding the package to `scripts` in package.json

**Note:** this is not needed nowadays with the existence of `npx`. It was a technique from before `npx` was introduced. Adding it here for the sake of having a more complete list.

#### Base package

This is a manual alternative to `npx` - a package can be added to the `scripts` section in package.json so it looks like this

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "author": "yourself",
    "scripts": {
        /* other scripts */
        "jest": "jest"
    },
    /* dependencies and other properties */
}
```

With that you will be able to use `npm` as if it's `npx`. Note that you have to add `run` to execute the script:

```
npm run jest --init
```

it still launches the local `jest` installation for the operation.

#### Adding a one off process

As an alternative, the command you want to run can be added as a script. Then you can run it once and delete it from package.json. First alter the file to look like this

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "author": "yourself",
    "scripts": {
        /* other scripts */
        "oneoff": "jest --init"
    },
    /* dependencies and other properties */
}
```

Then you can execute

```
npm run oneoff
```

And finally you can delete `"oneoff": "jest --init"`

### Directly addressing the package

As you found out, you can also use

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest --init
```

to run `jest`. This will work but it is longer and more annoying to type. Also, you have to know where the directory of the package is.

On Linux, the directory `./node_modules/.bin/` can also be added to the  `PATH` environment variable. It allows you to just execute `jest --init` or use any other package, however it's also dangerous and unneeded.

## Running globally (not recommended)

You can install the package globally. This will allows you to run it independently from your current project:

```
npm install --global jest
```

This will still allow you to use `jest --init`, however it is also potentially problematic.

1. It requires you to install an extra system package. It's possible you don't have permissions for this or otherwise you don't want to do it.
2. If you start working on a new project, you still have a single global installation of the Node package. If both projects use different versions of the Node package and those are incompatible, you might run into problems.
3. Similarly, if you upgrade the node package *in the project*, or the *global one* but not both, then you might have a similar problem with incompatibilities.