# ELIFECYCLE error encountered when attempting to start React app using "npm start"

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I'm encountering the error below when trying to start my React app.

```
 events.js:174
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^ Error: spawn powershell.exe ENOENT
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) Emitted 'error' event at:
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! my_app@0.1.0 start:
 react-scripts start npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed
 at the my_app@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
 problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm
 ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
 /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-15T14_43_41_420Z-debug.log
```

I'm using a bash terminal inside VSCODE on a Windows 10 system.

Additional info which maybe relevant:

- Command used to install create-react-app --> `npm install create-react-app`
- Command used to create new react app --> `npx create-react-app my_app`
- NPM version --> `6.14.4`

Please note that I'm a complete beginner when it comes to React. Would greatly appreciate any inputs offered on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more info? Are you using `yarn start`?

Also a side note - if using `npx` you don't have to install `create-react-app`. This answer explains the differences between `npx` and `npm` - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm#:~:text=npx%20is%20a%20npm%20package,it%20in%20a%20single%20step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm#:%7E:text=npx%20is%20a%20npm%20package,it%20in%20a%20single%20step).

Comment: No, I'm using npm start. Yes, I've used npx. Ok, I'll take a look, thanks!