# Why react CLI does not installing template as typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

After running `npm init react-app new-app --template typescript` it simply creates a javascript template project, not typescript. I want to create a typescript project using CLI.

Node JS version: 15.9.0 
NPM version: 7.0.15

Comment: Have you tried `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`?

Comment: Of course. It works fine, But why ```npm``` not working. What is the mistake in this command?

Comment: @ChosenUser Command seems right. Works for me Node JS - 10.16 and npm - 6.14

Comment: Npm and npx are two different things. Npm is package manager while npx is package executor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm

Comment: @szczocik My first instinct was that but `npm init `can take an `initializer` which in our case is `react-app` translated to `npx create-react-app`

Comment: Thank you all of you guys. I got my answer.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-init) suggest that, in v7, you need `--`: `npm init react-app -- new-app --template typescript`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's exactly what I am looking for. A big thanks for your time.

Comment: Then why have you accepted rustyBucketBay's answer below, which *doesn't* tell you that? It just links to the (wrong!) docs. You don't have to (and shouldn't) accept any answer that's posted, first check that they actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-init), in NPM v7:

> Any additional options will be passed directly to the command, so `npm init foo -- --hello` will map to `npx create-foo --hello`.

This is subtly *different* to [v6](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-init), where:

> Any additional options will be passed directly to the command, so `npm init foo --hello` will map to `npx create-foo --hello`.

Note the additional `--` for v7, which in your case would be:

```
npm init react-app -- new-app --template typescript
```