# Difference between npm and npx create-react-app installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just used both npm and npx installers of the react-app on my Mac as outlined on a different post and I was wondering what the difference between the two was. They each created a package.json, package-lock.json, and node_modules folder. Can I delete the npm created outer files?

[VSCode Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9SCw.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: *"I just used both npm and npx installers of the react-app on my Mac"* That's very vague. We can't help you if you don't show us the exact series of commands you used. Fundamentally, `npm` does various package creation and installation/uninstallation tasks, and `npx` **runs** the script you identify (which typically, but not always, then does package creationg and/or installation).

Answer (score 1):

The question has been perused and dissected in this stack overflow post [Difference between npx and npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm).
Basically, npx is used to download and execute resources and the packages are localized within your project. This helps to avoid the conflict that occurs when one version of a package in your project isn't compatible with the one in another project. So you can manage different projects without worrying about incompatibility of one with the other.