# Changed my PC, and now Next.js won't run local server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, next.js, next.js13

**PROBLEM**
I recently changed my PC from a MacBook Pro to a MacBook air. I cloned my Next.js repos, ran `npx run dev` to start the local server, and ran into the following terminal error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/briangrieco/Code Projects/portfolio/dev'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS**
I have made sure I'm on the latest version of Node.js (21.6.2) and that it matches my OS Bit (`node -p 'process.arch'` returns `arm64`, I'm on MacOS Sonoma).

I've deleted the package.lock.json file and the node_modules folder, then run `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install`, to no avail. I can't find a .next folder to delete.

Comment: Are you using git? Maybe you had your nextjs config in .gitignore by accident. Do you have acces to your old computer with the working repo?

Comment: Thank you but that's not it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, running `npm run dev` as opposed to `npx run dev` is all I had to do to fix this. No idea why, on my previous computer `npx run dev` worked fine.

Comment: If you're interested in further details, watch this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm